# Material UI Grid layout and width of individual items

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a custom library built on top of Material UI. I have my JSX as below;

```
<MyLayout container spacing={2}>
    <MyLayout item xs={9}>                    
        <MyComp1 />
    </MyLayout>
    <MyLayout item xs={2}>                    
        <MyComp2 />
    </MyLayout>
    <MyLayout item xs={1}>                    
        <MyComp3 />
    </MyLayout>
</MyLayout>
```

Now my question is for the 3rd one , where I have xs={1}, it occupies a larger width than what I would want. Is it possible to adjust the width it takes to make it smaller ?

Comment: Can you create a demo out of it? Using Codesandbox or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered nesting an additional grid container? Like:

```
  <Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={9}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={2}>
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={1}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>item</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

You can check out the [codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-v1dp9?file=/demo.js)